# How do I test snapshots as an authenticated user using jest?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redux, jestjs, redux-saga

I am developing an application Ruby on rails for backend and React for frontend. I have experience testing in RoR, so backend test has not been an issue. But I am new to react and I want to introduce frontend testing on the project.

I am using jest for testing, and so far I have no issues to test "public" (for non authenticated users) views. But I have not found how to test views where I need to be authenticated.

I am using redux to keep track of user login status, and redux saga to make the request to the backend.

By now I am not interested in testing the login process, I only want to make snapshot testing of my "restricted" pages

My app is working so far as I expected.

Any help would be appretiated, I am currently stuck

Comment: Why don't you set up the state in your tests to already be authenticated? Your React unit tests shouldn't have to care at all about actual network requests. Also FWIW snapshot tests are just change detection, they're not high quality tests.

Comment: Thank you, I was reading about it just now. I am wrapping my components in a provider an calling dispatch function to force user authentication.
I will introduce other test later, but as I mentioned I am just getting started, I want to at least make sure nothing breaks and every page is rendered